# I am implementing truth table for ex-nor gate. could it be implemented much simpler?

Tags: java, logic

This snippet takes inputs as boolean and returns output for ex-nor gate

```
public boolean exnor_gate(boolean a, boolean b) {
    if (a==true){
        if(b==true)
            //a1, =b=1 
            return true;
        else 
            //a=1, b=0
            return false;
    }
    else {
        if(b==true)
            //a=0, b=1
            return false;
        else 
            //a=0, b=0
            return true;
    } 
}
```

Is there any simple implementation for the above code?

Comment: Yes, the `^` operator.

Comment: What you have implemented is not an XOR gate's truth table, but an XNOR gate's. In Java that is `!(a ^ b)`

Comment: I'd use the `!=` operator actually for an XOR - somehow, it seems easier to understand than using `^`.  But as Erwin has pointed out, you've actually done a NXOR, which is the same as the `==` operator.

Comment: corrected function name from exor to exnor. Thanks @ErwinBolwidt and David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `^` operator, which is the XOR operator. You can implement it as such

```
public boolean exor_gate(boolean a, boolean b) {
  return a ^ b;
}
```

Here is a truth table of the results

```
A | B | XOR
-----------
T | T | F
T | F | T
F | T | T
F | F | F
```

**Edit**: As Erwin noted, you might be trying to implement the XNOR which is `!(a ^ b)` or `a == b`. This would be implemented as such

```
public boolean xnor_gate(boolean a, boolean b) {
  return a == b;
}
```

With truth table:

```
A | B | XNOR
------------
T | T | T
T | F | F
F | T | F
F | F | T
```